# Callback on a class template

Tags: c++, templates

The idea behind this was to have a template class that could create a vector of an specified size and call back to a function when the vector has been completely filled.

I had a working example using a static function as the callback:

```
template<class T>
class Intellivector
{
public:
    Intellivector(unsigned int size, std::function<void(std::vector<std::pair<T,bool>>)> slot)
    {
        this->size = size;
        vt.resize(size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        {
            vt.push_back({T(0),false});
        }

        this->slot = slot;
    }
    void set(unsigned int pos,T value, bool valid = true)
    {
        vt.at(pos)= {value,valid};
        isReady();
    }
    bool isReady()
    {
        bool ready = true;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(vt[i].second==false)
            {
                ready=false;
                printf("position %i not ready \n",i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ready && (this->slot != nullptr))
        {
            printf("CALL SLOT  \n");
            slot(vt);
        }
        return ready;
    }
    
    std::vector<std::pair<T,bool>> vt;

private:
    unsigned int size;
    std::function<void(std::vector<std::pair<T,bool>>)> slot =nullptr;
    //std::function<void(std::vector<std::pair<T,bool>>)> callback =nullptr;
};
```

Object is created like this for the static callback example:

```
 myvector = Intellivector<float>(3,MyClass::callbackFunction);
```

then myvector is used in another function which receives the values over an udp socket:

```
 hdglatlon.set(getIndexFromCan(message),vf[getIndexFromCan(message)]);
```

But then I tried to modify the code to allow passing a non-static function to the constructor to be used as callback, but can't manage to get it to work.

The following code fails at T{0}, as you would expect

```
    template<template<class> class A, typename B>
    Intellivector(unsigned int size, A<T> func_ptr, B obj_ptr)
    {
        this->size = size;
        vt.resize(size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        {
            vt.push_back({T(0),false});
        }

        this->slot=std::bind(func_ptr,obj_ptr);
    }
```

For this i tried to call the constructor like this:

```
myvector = Intellivector<float>(3,&MyClass::callbackFunction,this);
```

Also tried:

```
    template<typename B>
    Intellivector(unsigned int size, std::function<void(std::vector<std::pair<T,bool>>)>* slot, B obj_ptr)
    {
        this->size = size;
        vt.resize(size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<size;i++)
        {
            vt.push_back({T(0),false});
        }

        this->slot=std::bind(slot,obj_ptr);
    }
```

But then I get an error of "error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Intellivector'
note: candidate constructor template not viable: no known conversion from 'void (MyClass::*)(std::vector<std::pair<float, bool> >)' to 'std::function<void (std::vector<std::pair<float, bool> >)> *' for 2nd argument"

I'd appreciate any directions on how to get this to work, or any other alternatives to reach the same purpose. Thank you!

Comment: What is `vt`???

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: `A<T>` is a class type, not any kind of a function pointer type; your attempts don't make much sense to me. How are you calling this constructor? What are you passing for `func_ptr`? Show an example of the calling code that you hope to get to work.

Comment: Sorry about the missing info, I've edited the original question, hopefully now is fully readable.

Answer (score 0):

The high-level problem appears that you're reinventing the wheel.

What you should do is have a ctor that accepts a *template argument pack*, ignoring the type for a moment, and just `std::bind` the whole forwarded pack. Static method, free function, class method plus class pointer - you really don't care as long as you can `bind` it and store in a `std::function`.

For C++20 fancyness, you can add the [`std::invocable` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) to produce a nicer error message.

Comment: I also got the impression that I was trying to reinvent the wheel, but I'm not sure how a template argument pack could be used in my constructor, If you could provide a small example or another reference I would really appreciate it.